# How to implement custom dialog for accepting turn based multiplayer game invite?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I want to implement a custom dialog box on `onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation)` callback. It will have 2 options - 'accept' and 'reject'.

I successfully implemented the 'reject' action. Simplified code below -

```
@Override
public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
    String invitationId = invitation.getInvitationId();

    if (/*code for selecting 'reject' action*/) {
        Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.declineInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, invitationId);
    }
}
```

**But how do I implement 'accept' action?** Specifically from just `Invitation` object. I will need `TurnBasedMatch` object to start the match on invited players end.

The following link from google developers lists only the way to show default view to 'accept' (or 'reject') game.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#handling_invitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this on my own. Below is the simplified code to 'accept' the game invitation and get the match object -

```
PendingResult<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult> pendingResult = 
    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.acceptInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, invitationId);

pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult result) {
        if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            TurnBasedMatch match = result.getMatch();
            // do something with match ...
        }
    }
});
```